# Flyway DB migration for multiple code base in a single db

Tags: flyway

I have 3 code bases:
1) db_product1
2) db_product2
3) db_common

db_common contains code that goes into both products, while db_product1 and db_product2 are the code bases for 2 separate databases.

ie, the Product1 database gets db_product1 and db_common
the Product2 database gets db_product2 and db_common

The versioning across products will not be shared, nor will common.  So, we could be at v1.3.5 for product1, v9.3.1 for product2, and v6.2.4

Thus, I am trying to figure out how to manage 2 code bases into a single database schema.  Relying on versions will not be sufficient, due to the conflicting ordering.

In looking through the documentation, I'm guessing that I can use two separate metadata tables.  Ie during the init or migrate commands, use Flyway.table=schema_history_common and Flyway.table=schema_history_product1, depending on which code base I'm installing.

Does this seem reasonable?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that seems reasonable. Ideally you would want to go to a schema per product, as this will provide you with clean namespacing and avoid any conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for verifying.  Yes, we are using separate schemas for the different "products" - that's what I meant by a Product1 database and a Product2 database.  The meat of the question remains - we want both "Product1" stuff and "common" stuff in a single database, and want to track both separately using Flyway.  Thus the separate Flyway.tables.  (We are using MySQL, which does not support schemas the way that Oracle or SQLServer do...)  Thanks!